# How to copy BODY theorem in a new tex file by newwrite latex?

Tags: theorems

I want copy body of all theorems to a new latex file. But I have an error. Please. help me!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs,amsfonts,amssymb,etoolbox,environ}
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theox}{Theorem}


\newenvironment{copyTheorem}{
    \newwrite\copyfile
    \immediate\openout\copyfile=xTheorem.tex


}{%
\immediate\closeout\copyfile
}

\AtBeginEnvironment{theo}{

        \immediate\write\copyfile{\string\begin{theox}}
        \immediate\write\copyfile{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}
        \immediate\write\copyfile{\string\end{theox}}   
}%end ex


\begin{document}
\begin{copyTheorem}
    \begin{theo}
        contents 1111111 111111
    \end{theo}  
    \begin{theo}
        contents 22222222 222222
    \end{theo}
\end{copyTheorem}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `extract` package can extract environments.

This MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs,amsfonts,amssymb,etoolbox,environ}
\usepackage[
active,                 % switch on extracting
generate=copyfile,   % name of the output .tex file
extract-env=theo     % name of the environment
]{extract}

\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{theox}{Theorem}



\begin{document}
    \begin{theo}
        contents 1111111 111111
        $\alpha$
    \end{theo}  
    \begin{theo}
        contents 22222222 222222
    \end{theo}
\end{document}
```

produces this extract file:

```
%% 
%% This is file, `copyfile.tex',
%% generated with the extract package.
%% 
%% Generated on :  2020/03/17,20:43
%% From source  :  environment_outputB.tex
%% Using options:  active,generate=copyfile,extract-env=theo
%% 
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
        contents 1111111 111111
        $\alpha$

\end{theo}

\begin{theo}
        contents 22222222 222222

\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

The package also can write a preamble to the target file so that it can be compiled with latex. Commands can also be extracted.

Still not an answer to the question asked, about using newwrite.

---

Original response:

Not an answer, because I don't know enough (yet).

It looks like `\BODY` is defined by `\NewEnviron` command (which is for document authors):

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs,amsfonts,amssymb,etoolbox,environ}
%\usepackage{etoolbox,environ}
%\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}
%\newtheorem{theox}{Theorem}
\NewEnviron{theo}{ \immediate\write\copyfile{\string\begin{theox}}
            \immediate\write\copyfile{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}
        \immediate\write\copyfile{xxx}
        \immediate\write\copyfile{\string\end{theox}}}[]
%\NewEnviron{theox}{Theorem}[]


\newenvironment{copyTheorem}{
    \newwrite\copyfile
    \immediate\openout\copyfile=xTheorem.tex


}{%
\immediate\closeout\copyfile
}

%%\AtBeginEnvironment{theo}{%
%%        \immediate\write\copyfile{\string\begin{theox}}
%%%        \immediate\write\copyfile{\unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}}
%%%        xxx \BODY xxx
%%          \immediate\write\copyfile{\expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\BODY}}
%%        \immediate\write\copyfile{xxx}
%%        \immediate\write\copyfile{\string\end{theox}}   
%%}%end ex


\begin{document}
\begin{copyTheorem}
    \begin{theo}
        contents 1111111 111111
        $\alpha$
    \end{theo}  
    \begin{theo}
        contents 22222222 222222
    \end{theo}
\end{copyTheorem}


\end{document}
```

which fills `xTheorem.tex` file with:

```
\begin{theox}
contents 1111111 111111 $\alpha $
xxx
\end{theox}
\begin{theox}
contents 22222222 222222
xxx
\end{theox}
```

Now, `environ` documentation says, for package authors: "Now, amsmath defines \collect@body for us. But that package may not be loaded, and we don’t want to have to load the whole thing just for this one macro." etc

So it looks like it should be possible to write a macro using the "long" version with `\Collect@Body`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xparse`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath,mathrsfs,amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse} % better than environ

\newtheorem{theoreminner}{Theorem}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% allocate a write stream and the boolean variable
\iow_new:N \g_jack_theorem_iow
\bool_new:N \g_jack_theorem_write_bool

% user level commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\writetheorems}{m}
 {% #1 is the file name
  % open it
  \iow_open:Nn \g_jack_theorem_iow { #1 }
  % remember to close it
  \AtEndDocument { \iow_close:N \g_jack_theorem_iow }
  % enable writing
  \bool_gset_true:N \g_jack_theorem_write_bool
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{theorem}{o+b}
 {
  % typeset the theorem
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\begin{theoreminner}}{\begin{theoreminner}[#1]}
  #2
  \end{theoreminner}
  % possibly write it out
  \bool_if:NT \g_jack_theorem_write_bool
   {% writing is enabled
    % first the \begin part
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
     {
      \iow_now:Nn \g_jack_theorem_iow { \begin{theorem} }
     }
     {
      \iow_now:Nn \g_jack_theorem_iow { \begin{theorem}[#1] }
     }
    % write the body
    \iow_now:Nn \g_jack_theorem_iow { #2 }
    % the \end part
    \iow_now:Nn \g_jack_theorem_iow { \end{theorem} }
   }
 }{}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\writetheorems{\jobname-thm}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Someone]
contents 1111111 111111
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
contents 22222222 222222
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

### The PDF

[image]

### The `-thm` file

```latex
\begin {theorem}[Someone]
contents 1111111 111111
\end {theorem}
\begin {theorem}
contents 22222222 222222
\end {theorem}
```

Comment: That's awsome. But can  you keep numerical order of theorem? example:  in my main document the theorems are not in an order (theorem 1, 2, 5), and I want to keep the order of these theorems when I copy to a new file.